# Select query count specific value in a column stored result in a DataSet

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I figure it out my answer is on the bottom of this section.

Any help would be great Thank you.

I Have a table with a column called Rank which can hold values from 1-5

What i'm trying to do is get Data Back stored into a Data Set to be display later on

for example

```
Rank
_____

4
3
5
4
2
```

my sql query i have now.

```
select rank, COUNT(*) as rankCount from Result group by rank
```

i would like to display

Five rank = 1

Four rank = 2

Three rank = 1

Two rank = 1

One rank = 0

```
myDataSet.Table[0].Rows[0].Field<int>("rank"); ??
```

not sure how to do this any help would be great thank you.

same query

```
select rank, COUNT(*) as rankCount from Result group by rank

myDataTable = MyDataSet.Table[0];

string rank5 = string.Empty;

Foreach(DataRow row in myDataTable.Rows){

       if(row["rank"].ToString() == "5"){
         rank5 - row["rankCount"].ToString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this not work? `myDataSet.Table[0].Rows[0].Field<int>("rankCount");`

Comment: have not tried not sure to how get specific value for example if its rank 5 how do i get that count?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RankGroup
{
    public int Rank { get; set; }
    public int RankCount { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Rank Number: {0} Rank Number Count: {1}", Rank, RankCount);
    }
}

var rankGroups = myDataSet.Table[0].Rows.Cast<Row>().Select(r =>
                                    new RankGroup
                                    {
                                        Rank = r.Field<int>("rank"),
                                        RankCount = r.Field<int>("rankCount")
                                    }

foreach(var rankGroup in rankGroups)
{
    Console.WriteLine(rank);
}
```

Comment: using asp.net i have a section on a web page called 5 how do i put that specific count in that field?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing is much more suited (and faster) in the database. So I would do:

(I have a table with similar data, so my "targetType" equates to your "rank".)

```
select targetType,
case targetType
when 1 then 'One'
when 2 then 'Two'
when 3 then 'Three'
when 4 then 'Four'
when 5 then 'Five'
else '' end + ' Rank' as Description,
count(1) [Count]
from Logs
where targetType between 1 and 5
group by targetType
order by 1


targetType  Description Count
1            One Rank    264
2            Two Rank    248
3            Three Rank  692
4            Four Rank   441
```